# Change wording on Woocommerce Checkout page

Tags: woocommerce

Thanks to help here:
[Change Billing details text to Shipping details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44419189/change-billing-details-text-to-shipping-details-on-woocommerce-checkout-page)
I could change Billing details text on Woocommerce Checkout page by adding this to functions.php in Child theme:

```
function wc_billing_field_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    switch ( $translated_text ) {
        case 'Billing details' :
            $translated_text = __( 'Billing Info', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'wc_billing_field_strings', 20, 3 );
```

What are the codes to change these 3 additional texts with different wording:
Additional information, PRODUCT & QUANTITY
(see screenshot):
[Woocommerce Checkout Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrXkt.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It would be better to override the checkout/form-checkout.php and checkout/review-order.php**

Or You can use `gettext` filter .

> This filter hook is applied to the translated text by the
>   internationalization functions (__(), _e(), etc.)

```
function th_wc_order_review_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {

  if(is_checkout()){
    switch ($translated_text) {
      case 'Billing details' :
        $translated_text = __( 'Billing Info', 'woocommerce' );
        break;
      case 'Additional information':
        $translated_text = __('New Field Name', 'woocommerce');
        break;
     case 'Your order':
        $translated_text = __('My Order', 'woocommerce');
        break;
     case 'Product':
        $translated_text = __('Your Product', 'woocommerce');
        break;
    }
  }
  return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'th_wc_order_review_strings', 20, 3 );
```

Try changing the above code to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks melvin, That worked but only for "Billing details". How to change  Additional information, PRODUCT & QUANTITY. I'm adding the code to functions.php in Child theme. The page is here: (https://tokyopicnics.com/checkout/) Thanks!

Comment: @Clawdius Check my answer. I have updated. Also you can override template file  to change the label if there are no other issues

Comment: @Clawdius There was case sensitive issues in my answer that i have updated. Check now. Hope everything works fine

Comment: That's great! 3 done! but "Additional information" still won't change. Don't think there is a template file. Can't find it so using functions.php on Child. Thanks!

Comment: Can you find the template file in which the `Additional information` is written using a text editor ? Also have you checked there is no case sensitive issues ? @Clawdius

Comment: You could see something like this `__( 'Additional information', 'woocommerce' ) ` in your template. You have to type the same to change the text

Comment: It was a case sensitive issue: case 'Additional information': had a capital i. All fine now. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Clawdius Happy i could help. Please upvote the answer by clicking on the up arrow icon on the left side of answer once you have sufficient reputation so that someone will find the answer  helpful

Comment: @Clawdius Happy i could help. Please upvote the answer by clicking on the up arrow icon on the left side of answer once you have sufficient reputation so that someone will find the answer  helpful

Comment: Sorry again, one more issue after this fix: The site is bilingual English/Japanese. On Japanese site on the homepage there are 4 Picnic products. When I click "Reserve" then "Add to Cart" next to it, it goes to English Checkout page not Japanese. It was ok before. Can you help? Thanks!

Comment: @Clawdius i don't know much about that. It can be any wpml issues

Comment: @Clawdius is that issue still there when you remove the above answer ?

Comment: yes, I activated the main theme and the issue was still there

Comment: @Clawdius try removing the code i give you and if still issue persists, then that's something else

Comment: I also tried removing code from child and issue still there

Comment: @Clawdius So this issue is something else. Find your recent changes you made to any of the pages and change it back

Comment: Ok Thanks for your help

Comment: @Clawdius sorry for i couldn't help

Comment: Hi again. That issue is fixed now but now the homepage is loading very slowly (10 seconds). I found it's because of the code you gave for functions.php. When I use Child-theme with code - very slow. When I change to main theme with no code - normal. When I add the code to main theme in editor - back to very slow. Do you know how I can keep the code and normal homepage loading speed? Thanks!

Comment: @Clawdius the filter i gave you check each translation on every page for matching text. I have given an `is_checkout` function to ensure that the switch is executed only in checkout page. When the match is found the replace is applied. . This is the maximum i can optimize. So if the delay is due to code, then it is better to override the template file.

Comment: Thanks again! Will try

Comment: I'm getting a 502 error when adding a new code snippet with this code

Comment: @JulienVan Where did you add this code? Just checked now and it works

Comment: @melvin in the Code Snippet plugin