# Change 'Ship to a Different Address' title Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How to change woocommerce checkout 'Ship to a Different Address' section title to 'Partial Pay'?

Comment: please tell us about your attempts to solve the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change "Billing Details" text to "Shipping Details" on Woocommerce checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44419189/change-billing-details-text-to-shipping-details-on-woocommerce-checkout-page)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to your functions.php

```
function shipchange( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
switch ( $translated_text ) {
case 'Ship to a different address?' :
$translated_text = __( 'Partial Pay', 'woocommerce' );
break;
}
return $translated_text;
}

add_filter('gettext', 'shipchange', 20, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, it can be done with Loco Translate plugin, by updating woocommerce plugin

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).